# How to define a comparison between a child and a parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I am creating an state machine, where state is a class. I need to be able group some states in stategroups. Those groups inherit from states (very similar behavior). I need to be able to compare state with groups same way I am comparing states `operator ==`.

What is the best way to do this (in C++03 and C++11)? Is there an idiom or pattern?

I've made virtual method `IsEqual` and redefined it in stategroup. 
`Operator ==` calls it twice like: `return (lhs == rhs) || (rhs == lhs)`.
But It seems to complicated. And I am not sure if it is clear and readeble.

```
//Simplified version of the code

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// A state, which can be transioned from/to, and which can represent the current state
class IState {
    //cannot copy/assign
    IState(const IState& s) {}
    IState& operator=(const IState&) { return *this; }
protected:
    //protected constructor makes it abstract
    IState() {}

    virtual bool IsEqual(const IState& other)const { return this == &other; }
public:
    virtual ~IState() {}

    bool operator==(const IState& other)const { return IsEqual(other) || other.IsEqual(*this); }
    bool operator!=(const IState& other)const { return !(*this == other); }


};




class State : public IState {
public:
    State() {}
};

class StateGroup : public State {
    vector<State*> states;

    //if parent would be equal, child is equal too
    //else need to check vector for a equal ptr
    //it could be called recursively if needed
    virtual bool IsEqual(const IState& other)const {
        return State::IsEqual(other) ||
            find(states.begin(), states.end(), &other) != states.end();
    }
public:
    StateGroup() {}
    virtual bool AddState(State& st) {
        if (find(states.begin(), states.end(), &st) != states.end()) return false;
        states.push_back(&st);
        return true;
    }
};


//see if it is working

int main()
{
    State s1, s2;
    StateGroup sg1, sg2;
    sg1.AddState(s1);
    sg2.AddState(s2);

    State* ps = &s1;
    bool b;

    cout << boolalpha;

    cout << "states" << endl;
    b = s1 == *ps;
    cout << "result of s1 == *ps is " << b << " expected true" << endl;
    b = s1 != *ps;
    cout << "result of s1 != *ps is " << b << " expected false" << endl;

    b = s1 == s2;
    cout << "result of s1 == s2 is " << b << " expected false" << endl;
    b = s1 != s2;
    cout << "result of s1 != s2 is " << b << " expected true" << endl;

    cout << "groups" << endl;
    b = sg1 == sg2;
    cout << "result of sg1 == sg2 is " << b << " expected false" << endl;
    b = sg1 != sg2;
    cout << "result of sg1 != sg2 is " << b << " expected true" << endl;

    cout << "states and groups" << endl;
    b = s1 == sg1;
    cout << "result of s1 == sg1 is " << b << " expected true" << endl;
    b = s1 != sg1;
    cout << "result of s1 != sg1 is " << b << " expected false" << endl;

    b = s1 == sg2;
    cout << "result of s1 == sg2 is " << b << " expected false" << endl;
    b = s1 != sg2;
    cout << "result of s1 != sg2 is " << b << " expected true" << endl;

    b = sg1 == s1;
    cout << "result of sg1 == s1 is " << b << " expected true" << endl;
    b = sg1 != s1;
    cout << "result of sg1 != s1 is " << b << " expected false" << endl;

    b = sg1 == s2;
    cout << "result of sg1 == s2 is " << b << " expected false" << endl;
    b = sg1 != s2;
    cout << "result of sg1 != s2 is " << b << " expected true" << endl;

    cout << "state and state pointer pointing to group" << endl;
    ps = &sg1;
    b = s1 == *ps;
    cout << "result of s1 == *ps is " << b << " expected true" << endl;
    b = s1 != *ps;
    cout << "result of s1 != *ps is " << b << " expected false" << endl;

    b = s2 == *ps;
    cout << "result of s2 == *ps is " << b << " expected false" << endl;
    b = s2 != *ps;
    cout << "result of s2 != *ps is " << b << " expected true" << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

I am getting output as expected.
Unit tests in original code passed also.
Tested in IAR Embedded Workbench (Renesas V850), Visual studio and Code::Blocks(GCC).

So I think it works. But I do not like that double comparation in `operator==`.

Comment: If you cast the parent to child, then you can use the comparison operator

Comment: why do you have a double comparison in the first place? Maybe it is something obvious, but I dont see it.  Why is `return IsEqual(other);`  not sufficient?

Comment: If StateGroup contains a State I need to operator ==  between them to return true.
But i need it in both ways. 
StateGroup == State and State == StateGroup.

Comment: @PhoenixBlue I cannot cast parent to child. There is vector inside child. If I cast parent to child, it will try to access some random memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it.

I have made virtual `operator ==` in parent and it calls of `other.IsEqual`

```
virtual bool operator==(const IState& other)const { other.IsEqual(*this); }
```

And then redefined it in StateGroup to

```
virtual bool operator==(const IState& other)const { return IsEqual(other); }
```

Double comparison is removed and it is still ensured when comparing State and StateGroup, `StateGroup::IsEqual` is used in both ways.

```
class IState {
    //cannot copy/assign
    IState(const IState& s) {}
    IState& operator=(const IState&) { return *this; }
protected:
    //protected constructor makes it abstract
    IState() {}

    virtual bool IsEqual(const IState& other)const { return this == &other; }
public:
    virtual ~IState() {}

    //bool operator==(const IState& other)const { return IsEqual(other) || other.IsEqual(*this); }
    virtual bool operator==(const IState& other)const { other.IsEqual(*this); }
    bool operator!=(const IState& other)const { return !(*this == other); }
};

class State : public IState {
public:
    State() {}
};

class StateGroup : public State {
    vector<State*> states;

    //if parent would be equal, child is equal too
    //else need to check vector for a equal ptr
    //it could be called recursively if needed
protected:
    virtual bool IsEqual(const IState& other)const {
        return State::IsEqual(other) ||
            find(states.begin(), states.end(), &other) != states.end();
    }

public:
    StateGroup() {}
    virtual bool AddState(State& st) {
        if (find(states.begin(), states.end(), &st) != states.end()) return false;
        states.push_back(&st);
        return true;
    }
    virtual bool operator==(const IState& other)const { return IsEqual(other); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can redefine the operator in both directions.

Here is an example that worked with me:

*.h*:

```
class B;

class A
{
    protected:
        int a;
        int b;

    public:
        A(int aa, int bb);

    friend bool operator==(const A & lhs, const B & rhs);
    friend bool operator==(const B & lhs, const A & rhs);
};

class B : public A
{
    protected:
        int c;

    public:
        B(int aa, int bb, int cc);
};
```

*.cpp*:

```
A::A(int aa, int bb) : a(aa), b(bb)
{}
B::B(int aa, int bb, int cc) : A(aa, bb), c(cc)
{}

bool operator==(const A & lhs, const B & rhs)
{
    return (lhs.a == rhs.a) && (lhs.b == rhs.b);
}

bool operator==(const B & lhs, const A & rhs)
{
    return (lhs.a == rhs.a) && (lhs.b == rhs.b);
}
```

I have made the following test:

```
int main()
{
    A a1(2, 5);
    B b1(2, 5, 0);

    std::cout << (a1 == b1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (b1 == a1) << std::endl;

    B b2(3, 4, 2);

    std::cout << (a1 == b2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (b2 == a1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As expected, it outputs:

> 1
>   1
>   0
>   0

I hope it helps.

Comment: It would not work with inheritance.
`A& pa00 = b00;
A& pa01 = b01;
std::cout << (pa00 == pa01) << std::endl;`

Comment: non member functions seemed elegant to me too, but I need to compare `State` and `StateGroup` pointed by `State*` or  `State&`